# How do I safely delay a web response in ASP.net?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a problem where when we initiate a REST resource from a third party (Twilio), the service responds so quickly, we don't have time to write our SID's to database. We can't tell the service to wait, as it returns the SID only when the service has initiated. The application itself can't hold the state, as there's no guarantee that the RESTful callback will reach the same instance of our application.

We've mitigated the problem by writing the SID's to a buffer table in the database, and we've tried some strategies for forcing the web response to wait, but using Thread.Sleep seems to be blocking other unrelated web responses and generally slowing down the server during peak load.

How can I gracefully ask a web response to hang on a minute while we check the database? Preferably without gumming up the whole server with blocked threads.

This is the code that initiates the service:

```
 private static void SendSMS(Shift_Offer so, Callout co,testdb2Entities5 db)
    {

        co.status = CalloutStatus.inprogress;
        db.SaveChanges();
        try
        {
            CallQueue cq = new CallQueue();
            cq.offer_id = so.shift_offer_id;
            cq.offer_finished = false;
            string ShMessage = getNewShiftMessage(so, co, db);
            so.offer_timestamp = DateTime.Now;
            string ServiceSID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

            var message = MessageResource.Create
                        (
                            body: ShMessage,
                            messagingServiceSid: ServiceSID,
                            to: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber(RCHStringHelpers.formatPhoneNumber(so.employee_phone_number)),
                            statusCallback: new Uri(TwilioCallBotController.SMSCallBackURL)
                        );
            cq.twilio_sid = message.Sid;
            db.CallQueues.Add(cq);
            db.SaveChanges();
            so.offer_status = ShiftOfferStatus.OfferInProgress;
            so.status = message.Status.ToString();
            so.twillio_sid = message.Sid;
            db.SaveChanges();

        }
        catch (SqlException e) //if we run into any problems here, release the lock to prevent stalling; 
                               //note to self - this should all be wrapped in a transaction and rolled back on error
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Failure in CalloutManager.cs at method SendSMS: /n" +
                            "Callout Id: " + co.callout_id_pk + "/n"
                            + "Shift Offer Id: " + so.shift_offer_id + "/n"
                            + e.StackTrace);
            ResetCalloutStatus(co, db);
            ReleaseLock(co, db);
        }
        catch (Twilio.Exceptions.ApiException e) 
        {
            ReleaseLock(co, db);
            ResetCalloutStatus(co, db);
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Message + "/n" + e.StackTrace);
        }

    }
```

This is the code that responds:

```
        public ActionResult TwilioSMSCallback()
        {
            //invalid operation exception occurring here
            string sid = Request.Form["SmsSid"];
            string status = Request.Form["SmsStatus"];
            Shift_Offer shoffer;
            CallQueue cq = null;

            List<Shift_Offer> sho = db.Shift_Offers.Where(s => s.twillio_sid == sid).ToList();
            List<CallQueue> cqi = getCallQueueItems(sid, db);
            if (sho.Count > 0)
            {
                shoffer = sho.First();
                if (cqi.Count > 0)
                {
                    cq = cqi.First();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (cqi.Count > 0)
                {
                    cq = cqi.First();
                    shoffer = db.Shift_Offers.Where(x => x.shift_offer_id == cq.offer_id).ToList().First();
                }
                else
                {
                    return new Twilio.AspNet.Mvc.HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
                }
            }

            Callout co = db.Callouts.Where(s => s.callout_id_pk == shoffer.callout_id_fk).ToList().First();
            shoffer.status = status;
            if (status.Contains("accepted"))
            {
                shoffer.offer_timestamp = DateTime.Now;
                shoffer.offer_status = ShiftOfferStatus.SMSAccepted + " " + DateTime.Now;
            }
            else if (status.Contains("queued") || status.Contains("sending"))
            {
                shoffer.offer_timestamp = DateTime.Now;
                shoffer.offer_status = ShiftOfferStatus.SMSSent + " " + DateTime.Now;
            }
            else if (status.Contains("delivered") || status.Contains("sent"))
            {
                shoffer.offer_timestamp = DateTime.Now;
                shoffer.offer_status = ShiftOfferStatus.SMSDelivered + " " + DateTime.Now;
                setStatus(co);
                if (cq != null){
                    cq.offer_finished = true;
                }
                CalloutManager.ReleaseLock(co, db);
            }
            else if (status.Contains("undelivered"))
            {
                shoffer.offer_status = ShiftOfferStatus.Failed + " " + DateTime.Now;
                setStatus(co);
                if (cq != null){
                    cq.offer_finished = true;
                }
                CalloutManager.ReleaseLock(co, db);
            }
            else if (status.Contains("failed"))
            {
                shoffer.offer_status = ShiftOfferStatus.Failed + " " + DateTime.Now;
                setStatus(co);
                if (cq != null){
                    cq.offer_finished = true;
                }
                cq.offer_finished = true;
                CalloutManager.ReleaseLock(co, db);
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
            return new Twilio.AspNet.Mvc.HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
```

This is the code that delays:

```
public static List<CallQueue> getCallQueueItems(string twilioSID, testdb2Entities5 db)
    {
        List<CallQueue> cqItems = new List<CallQueue>();
        int retryCount = 0;
        while (retryCount < 100)
        {
            cqItems = db.CallQueues.Where(x => x.twilio_sid == twilioSID).ToList();
            if (cqItems.Count > 0)
            {
                return cqItems;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            retryCount++;
        }
        return cqItems;
    }
```

Comment: what? why are you returning before the database writes the SID?  This question is quite broad with out posting any code,

Comment: It's not us returning before the database has written, it's a third party service.

Comment: Please explain the full problem, its unclear what you're asking otherwise. we do not know the architecture of what is occuring. please post code and a full explaination an we will answer properly

Comment: @ScubaSteve - that edit was not helpful. Please post an [mcve]. It is very difficult to help with a question that contains no code.

Comment: I will edit with code, hang on.

Comment: I think I understand. Code starts in `SendSMS`, this creates a request with a generated id to Twilio, calls twilo first and then saves the generated id. The response to the call comes in on a web api endpoint likely hosted on a different process or at least a different thread. Sound about right?

Comment: ^------ If that is correct: Why not save the id before you call the Twilio service (so reverse the order of calls)?

Comment: @Igor - The ID is generated by the service when the SMS is initiated, and returned to us immediately. The callbacks that follow come back with that same SID generated when the SMS is initiated.

TL;DR - the ID is generated at the same time the Twilio service starts

Comment: @ScubaSteve,  it sounds like you're dependent on the `cq.twilio_sid = message.Sid;` but that looks like that is the SID that you pass to it. If it is something returned by the service, then my guess is twilio would include it in the callback Request which is being made to your sever are you sure there is no PostParam/Header with the equivalent value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good APIs™ let the consumer specify an ID that they want their message to be associated with. I have never used Twilio myself, but I have read their API Reference for [Creating a Message Resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource#create-a-message-resource) now, and sadly it seems like they don't provide a parameter for this. But there's still hope!

#### Potential solution (preferred)

Even though there isn't an explicit parameter for it, maybe you can specify slightly different callback URLs for each message that you create? Assuming that your `CallQueue` entities have a unique `Id` property, you could let the callback URL for each message contain a query string parameter specifying this ID. Then you can handle the callbacks without knowing the Message Sid.

To make this work, you would reorder things in the `SendSMS` method so that you save the `CallQueue` entity before invoking the Twilio API:

```
db.CallQueues.Add(cq);
db.SaveChanges();

string queryStringParameter = "?cq_id=" + cq.id;
string callbackUrl = TwilioCallBotController.SMSCallBackURL + queryStringParameter;

var message = MessageResource.Create
(
    [...]
    statusCallback: new Uri(callbackUrl)
);
```

You would also modify the callback handler `TwilioSMSCallback` so that it looks up the `CallQueue` entity by its ID, which it retrieves from the `cq_id` querystring parameter.

#### Solution that is almost guaranteed to work (but requires more work)

Some cloud services only allow callback URLs that exactly match one of the entries in a pre-configured list. For such services, the approach with varying callback URLs won't work. If this is the case for Twilio, then you should be able to solve your problem using the following idea.

Compared to the other approach, this one requires bigger changes to your code, so I will only give a brief description and let you work out the details.

The idea is to make `TwilioSMSCallback` method work even if the `CallQueue` entity doesn't yet exist in the database:

- If there is no matching `CallQueue` entity in the database, `TwilioSMSCallback` should just store the received message status update in a new entity type `MessageStatusUpdate`, so that it can be dealt with later.
- "Later" is at the very end of `SendSMS`: Here, you would add code to fetch and process any unhandled `MessageStatusUpdate` entities with matching `twilio_sid`.
- The code that actually processes the message status update (updating the associated `Shift_Offer`, etc.) should be moved away from `TwilioSMSCallback` and be placed in a separate method that can also be called from the new code at the end of `SendSMS`.

With this approach, you would also have to introduce some kind of locking mechanism to avoid race conditions between multiple threads/processes trying to process updates for the same `twilio_sid`.

Comment: Ahhh, this is interesting. I will look into this.

Comment: The more I look at this solution, the more I love it - we are definitely going to do this.

Comment: @ScubaSteve: Thanks! I hope Twilio allows the use of query string parameters. Otherwise you'll have to make other changes to your code to make it work regardless of the timing between database updates in `SendSMS` and the callback handler.

Comment: I don't see why they wouldn't allow it (in this manner). The URL's are entirely specified by us. We should be able to read that URL call with the parameter supplied when the resource is created. 

It may be possible to define the parameter in the resource itself, but I'll have to dig around the API reference docs to figure that out. But I don't see why it'd have a problem with a numbered URL.

Answer (score 1):

You really should not delay a RESTful call. Make it a 2-step operation, one for starting it, and one for getting the state. The latter you may call more than once, until the operation has safely completed, is light-weight and allows also for a progress indicator or state feedback to the caller, if you desire so.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it's 3rd party service that only returns an SID once your initiate the process, otherwise I'd agree. Start the service, get the SID, then flag when we're ready to get callbacks.

Comment: @ScubaSteve if you want to resolve your question, post all the relevant information in the questions e.g there is a 3rd party service, that only returns the SID. Its difficult to make a concise answer otherwise

Comment: A Windows service, right? Could you elevate the process priority of it in order to force it to reply faster? Please note that doing so, it may have an adverse effect on the whole server.

Comment: No, a third party RESTful service. Clarified above.

Comment: Ok, then ... what's about writing a batch script which reads the request from a database or file and make the call to the service off-line? If you have your feedback and handshaking over the database, you may delegate the operation to the system, while the caller app uses your RESTful API to get info about the state. I do the exact same thing for SMS on Linux systems.

Comment: @JohannesSchidlowski - I'm not sure I follow.

When we initiate the SMS message, the 3rd party service returns an SID. When the service makes status callbacks to us, it does so with the SID. We don't have the option to do any of this off-line, as far as I can tell.

Comment: I may not be following what you're suggesting though, so bear with me.

Comment: 1. Your app calls your API and initialises the process, returns a "random" handle" to the caller and writes a command to a table, and also the handle. E.g. phone number, title, text, state=0 and the handle.
2. Your server polls or gets notified and runs the code, and updates the state accordingly.
3. The caller app informs itself periodically about the state.

Comment: @JohannesSchidlowski - I'm sorry, I still don't follow what you're getting at. Are you saying that this is what my app does, or what it should do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186884/discussion-between-johannes-schidlowski-and-scuba-steve).

Answer (score -1):

Async/await can help you not to block your threads.

You can try `await Task.Delay(...).ConfigureAwait(false)` instead of `Thread.Sleep()`

**UPDATE**

I see you have some long running logic in `TwilioSMSCallback` and I believe this callback should be executed as fast as possible as it's coming from Twilio services (there can be penalties).

I suggest you to move your sms status processing logic to the end of `SendSMS` method and poll database there with `async/await` until you get the sms status. This however will keep `SendSMS` request active on the caller side, so better to have separate service which will poll database and call your api when something changes.